# GnuRadio not working on OS X 10.9.4 with HackRF One

Tags: python, macos, gtk, gnuradio

I just got my ne HackRF from Kickstarter. Works great with SDR# on Windows, so the product is ok.
To have a real use of it, i tried to get GNURadio working on my Mac, following this official tutorial: https://github.com/robotastic/homebrew-hackrf

However, running gnuradio after the compilation fails:

```
Bella:~ feejai$ gnuradio-companion

/usr/local/bin/gnuradio-companion:70: GtkWarning: Das Symbol »gnuradio-grc« konnte
nicht gefunden werden, ebenso wenig wie das Thema »hicolor«. Möglicherweise müssen Sie
es installieren.
Sie können sich eine Kopie herunterladen unter:
    http://icon-theme.freedesktop.org/releases
  try: gtk.window_set_default_icon(gtk.IconTheme().load_icon('gnuradio-grc', 256, 0))
Warning: Block with key "analog_agc2_xx" already exists.
    Ignoring: /usr/local/Cellar/gnuradio/3.6.5.1/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/analog_agc2_xx.xml
Warning: Block with key "analog_agc_xx" already exists.
    Ignoring: /usr/local/Cellar/gnuradio/3.6.5.1/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/analog_agc_xx.xml
Warning: Block with key "analog_cpfsk_bc" already exists.
    Ignoring: /usr/local/Cellar/gnuradio/3.6.5.1/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/analog_cpfsk_bc.xml
Warning: Block with key "analog_ctcss_squelch_ff" already exists.
    Ignoring: /usr/local/Cellar/gnuradio/3.6.5.1/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/analog_ctcss_squelch_ff.xml
Warning: Block with key "analog_dpll_bb" already exists.

....

Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
```

I don't even know why the first error message is in German, my operating system and all environment variables are set to English.

This might be a problem of python and xquartz, have seen similar error messages when googling all over gtk+ - but no solution yet.

Comment: Have a look at this post for some more info https://machinaut.github.io/posts/hackrf/

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
> ```

This error can occur if GNU Radio is compiled against a different version of Python than is used at runtime.

In my own case, I was compiling GNU Radio from source, and had Python installed from MacPorts; the solution was to include the option `-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/opt/local/lib/libpython2.7.dylib` in the `cmake` command when configuring GNU Radio (note that the `/opt/local/lib` part is specific to MacPorts Python). I found this advice [in this blog post](http://blog.lvbernal.com/2014/04/error-fatal-python-error.html).

I can't claim certainty that this specific change will work, as you might have some other mismatch, but I hope this helps figure out what's going on.

(If you're willing to try using MacPorts instead of Homebrew, I can say that HackRF works fine "out of the box" with its packages of gnuradio and gr-osmosdr.)

Comment: Thanks a ton. This worked for me. The command I used was: `cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib ../` (I installed python with Homebrew).

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm new I can't "Vote Up" Kevin's reply, but that's the gist of the issue: mismatched Python executable and library linkage.

Notes:

- If you are not already subscribed to the GNU Radio users discussion list, you'll find it a great resource for such questions.  https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/discuss-gnuradio
- MacPorts provides a "hackrf" port, which I keep up to date with their GIT master.  You can often use that instead of installing from source by hand ("sudo port install hackrf").  MacPorts also provides releases of GNU Radio and UHD ("sudo port install gnuradio", "sudo port install uhd") as well as devel versions which I also keep up to date with their respective GIT master branches ("sudo port install gnuradio-devel", "sudo port install uhd-devel").